# Mapping response objects(C#)

Tags: api

I am consuming an API mehod and it returns response as of type Product and below is the response class structure.

```
Public class Product    
{    
       public int Id;    
       public string Name;    
       public IList<Product> MasterProduct { get; set; }    
}
```

The API result include the product attributes along with IList. Since this API cannot be consumed directly though our windows client we have a wrapper web API which consume this API, for this in the local API we have defined similar Product class. The issue I am facing is when trying to map the attibues of external API with local. Below is what I am trying to do.

```
response = Response.Result.Select(x => new Product    
{    
Id=x.Id,    
Name=x.Name    
MasterProduct = x.MasterProduct.Cast<MasterProduct>().ToList()//tried below 
}).ToList();
```

but it fails with error as - Unable to cast object of type 'Api.Models.Product' to type 'App.DataContracts.Product'

The Masterproduct consist of hierarchal data .I am wondering if the approach I am taking is right or it has to be done through some method. Any suggestion or help would be appreciated.

Upon searching the web I came across some code where serpare method is being called to parse using Microsoft.Its.Data, but this was for single object where as in my case I have a List(Hierarchical).

Appreciate if someone can point to some linke/sampel to achive the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying serialization/deserialization would do. Below is the code 
Perhaps trying serialization/deserialization would do.

```
if (response.Result != null)    
{    

var serializedResponse = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Response.Result, Formatting.Indented);    
response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(serializedResponse);    

}).ToList();    
return response;
```

Comment: through inheritance have achieved the same, also above working tx.